# react office js textfield controlled component

Tags: reactjs, office-js

i tried to use officejs react component in it and for osme reason i cant get it to work properly..effective here is the code. it works in codepen but when i put hte same code in excel addin project, i cant get the value in the textfields.
Code in codepen(it works):

[https://codepen.io/manish_shukla01/pen/ReWWmM][1]

Code in my project in app file(does not work in the sense that handlechange events are not getting fired i believe so value of my state.value1 remains blank even when i input anything):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, ButtonType } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import Header from './Header';

import { TextField } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField';

import * as OfficeHelpers from '@microsoft/office-js-helpers';

export default class App extends React.Component<any,any,any>{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

                value1: '',
                 value2:'',
                 message:'Helloooo'
                 };

    this.handleChange1 = this.handleChange1.bind(this);
    this.handleChange2 = this.handleChange2.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange1(event) {
    this.setState({value1: event.target.value});


  }
    handleChange2(event) {
    this.setState({value2: event.target.value});

  }



  handleSubmit = async () => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({message: 'i got clicked'});
    try {
        //event.preventDefault();

        await Excel.run(async context => {
            /**
             * Insert your Excel code here
             */
            const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();

        // Read the range address
        range.load('address');

        // Update the fill color
        range.format.fill.color = 'blue';

        range.values = [[this.state.value2]];



        await context.sync();
        console.log(`The range address was ${range.address}.`);
        });
    } catch(error) {
        OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
        OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
    };
}

render() {

    return (
        <form className='ms-welcome'  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <Header logo='assets/logo-filled.png' title='Excel Analytics' message={this.state.message} />

            <TextField label="field1" 
  value={this.state.value1} onChange={this.handleChange1} 
required
/>
<Button className='ms-welcome__action' buttonType={ButtonType.primary} 

    onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Run
    </Button>

        </form>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue with Office UI Fabric TextField's "onChange" event and solved it using "onChanged" instead, which is deprecated as they say. But it worked for me.

First, add onChanged handler to TextField as below:

```
<TextField name="fieldName" label="field1" value={this.state.value1} onChanged={val => this.handleChange1("fieldName", val)} />
```

Also, note that "name" attribute is added to identify control in handleChange1.

Now change handler implementation as below:

```
handleChange1(name, value) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      result: {
          ...prevState.result,
          [name]: value
      }
    }));
  }
```

Hope this helps. Thanks!